# How to compile a Android SDK

Tags: java, android

I have a file system for an Android SDK that I need to compile but I have no idea how. Basic structure looks like this:

[image]

Any ideas? I've tried importing into Android studio and running gradle commands. I've tried importing into eclipse (which didn't work).

Comment: import project in Android studio and press `Shift+F10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't too bad.

I needed to import into Eclipse ADT (which is not longer supported I believe). Run once as a java project which generates a launch configuration then export as a runnable jar.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like an Eclipse project - if using Android Studio, you need to use the `Import Project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.)` option when importing.

If compiling fails, you may just need to reference the libraries the project is using - this should let you compile.

Comment: Is there anyway to compile to a JAR rather than apk using Android Studio?

Comment: @fuzzycuffs, No, an android app cannot be compiled to a JAR.

Comment: Do you need this compiled? Got a link to source?

Comment: I see - you could throw an NDA at me if you need to, I sort of do this everyday with games as well. Anyways, good luck!